# Spark History Server on Yarn only shows Python application

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have two spark contexts running on a box, 1 from python and 1 from scala. They are similarly configured, yet only the python application appears in the spark history page pointed to by the yarn tracking URL. Is there extra configuration I am missing here? (both run in `yarn-client` mode)

Comment: Could you check your Spark conf? `spark.eventLog.enabled` should be `true`, and `spark.eventLog.dir` should be pointed the correct location.

Comment: `spark.eventLog.dir hdfs:///spark-history`
`spark.eventLog.enabled true`

Comment: Could you also check the hdfs folder to see if the application wrote logs?

Comment: It is not for some reason...